# Tomcat behind Apache httpd with SSL and client-certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I try to evaluate a infrastructure for a customer on my local win32 machine. The infrastructure should be based on a j2ee webapp running on a tomcat (6.0.20+), behind a secur apache httpd (httpd-2.2.16/openssl-0.9.8) which only forwards those requests which are authorized (with a client certificate).

My approach was to solve the connection between tomcat and apache with the `mod_jk` and the corresponding `ajp13` protocol. The tomcat (ajp13) is running on port `8099`, i configured the `workers.properties` and my `mod_jk.conf` (and included it in `httpd.conf`). The connection works successful. The httpd is running on port `80` the tomcat runs his http port under `8084`. When sending a http request to `http://localhost/my-webapp-context`. The tomcats answers and showing up my webapp.

So far there are the following configuration files:

#### mod_jk.conf

```
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
#LoadModule    ssl_module  modules/mod_ssl.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     logs/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

JkMount /* balancer
```

#### workers.properties

```
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status
worker.list=balancer
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.error_escalation_time=0
worker.balancer.max_reply_timeouts=10
worker.balancer.balance_workers=node1
worker.node1.reference=worker.template
worker.node1.host=localhost
worker.node1.port=8109
worker.node1.activation=A
worker.balancer.balance_workers=node2
worker.node2.reference=worker.template
worker.node2.host=localhost
worker.node2.port=8099
worker.node2.activation=A
worker.template.type=ajp13
worker.template.socket_connect_timeout=5000
worker.template.socket_keepalive=true
worker.template.ping_mode=A
worker.template.ping_timeout=10000
worker.template.connection_pool_minsize=0
worker.template.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.template.reply_timeout=300000
worker.template.recovery_options=3
```

As described this works like a charm, now i read to several ssl tutorials. I already created a `server.key` (without private key because this seems to fail at win32 platform) and a `server.cer` which is certified by our local certification authority.

When it comes to the point of enabling `mod_ssl` i get several errors. I tried the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile conf/server.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration I produce the upcoming error (where the CN is my computer name in the lan), this is also the value i provided while generating the certification. The apache refuses to startup with this configuration and shows me the listed error.

### ***Update***

Now I finally get the apache with ssl and client certificates running:

#### mod_jk_ssl.conf

```
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
LoadModule    ssl_module  modules/mod_ssl.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     logs/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
 JkMount /* balancer

 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile conf/web.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/web.key
 SSLCACertificateFile conf/exampleCA.crt
 SSLVerifyClient require
 SSLVerifyDepth 2

 <IfDefine SSL>
     SSLRequireSSL
     SSLRequire           %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O}  eq "certification-authority" and  
     %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"BALVI"}
 </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have u tried accessing your app as "http://computer-name/my-webapp-context".

Comment: Did you try to pass the client SSL info to the server? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240796/pass-username-and-client-certificate-from-apache-to-tomcat-using-mod-jk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captain Obvious here. You did give the *my-computer-name* exactly as it is, including the domain name? If not, re-create the key one more time.

Comment: This finally lead me to rethink the certification, i missed several points which are very well explained here: http://www.garex.net/apache/#CACreate Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a redirect to apache to take you straight to your webapp

RedirectMatch ^/(.)/$ http://host.domain.com/your-webapp-context/?